# Access chrome local storage used in both content script and popup?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, content-script

I'm designing my first chrome extension and have run into a problem.

On my popups.js users can enter words and definitions that are saved as an array in chrome storage:

```
function save()
{
     chrome.storage.local.set({'words': words});
    chrome.storage.local.set({'definitions': definitions});
}
```

I would like to then load these words and definitions in my content script js like so:

```
function load()
{
    //load words from local storage
    chrome.storage.local.get('words', function (result) {
    if (result.words != "null") words = result.words;
    });

    //load definitions
    chrome.storage.local.get('definitions', function (result) {
        if (result.definitions != "null") definitions = result.definitions;
    });
}
```

However it does not load the data at all. I have made sure the data is saved before the content script is run.

I have looked into messaging but don't really understand it / know if that's even the right way to do it.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I now use sync instead of local: chrome.storage.sync

also I wasn't waiting for the storage to be loaded in, after I put my "start()" inside:

```
function load()
{
    //load words from local storage
    chrome.storage.local.get('words', function (result) {
    if (result.words != "null") words = result.words;
    });

    //load definitions
    chrome.storage.local.get('definitions', function (result) {
        if (result.definitions != "null") definitions = result.definitions;

start()
    });
}
```

it worked.

Comment: You should put the solution code in your answer. Your code listing has local.