# Getting a token value out of localStorage with a Chrome extension content-script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new to JavaScript and chrome extensions. I am writing an extension that needs to get a value out of the local storage of the web page to which it is a page action. Here is a snippet of manifest.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://url/*"],
            "js": ["user_story_template.js"]
        }
    ],
    "page_action": {
        "default_title": "Promotify",
        "default_icon": "promotify_20.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://url/*",
        "declarativeContent",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

Here is a snippet of the content script:

```
function get_token(){
  //alert("Starting processing...");
  var auth_token = ""; 
  chrome.storage.local.get('token', function(result){
  auth_token = result.token;
});
```

I have looked for answers and a lot of them say that this way should work. I should be able to do this from the content script. However, am not getting any value. I have tried using HTML also to no avail. When I go into the inspector on the page and look under resources there is a value for token in local storage.Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong? I am sure that I am missing something.

Some of the places I have looked for the answer:

[Easy way to get Local Storage Value to Content Script [Chrome Extension]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716960/easy-way-to-get-local-storage-value-to-content-script-chrome-extension)

[Access chrome local storage used in both content script and popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793173/access-chrome-local-storage-used-in-both-content-script-and-popup)

Comment: Are you trying to access the inspected page's local storage or the background page? You have to inject a script via a content script (or use the `executeScript` method) in order to access the inspected page's `localStorage` api.

Comment: `chrome.storage.local` is local storage *for the extension*, it's entirely separate from the website's own `localStorage`. As Daniel says, you'll need to actually run some code in the website's execution context to access its `localStorage`, which may need to send a message to pass that data to a different part of the extension.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Mind making that into an answer?

Comment: @Xan Naw, I don't have the time now to flesh it out into a good-enough answer for me to post. Somebody else can have at it.

Answer (score 1):

[chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) will only get your extension's storage, to get the storage belonging to the current page, you need to use [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in content scripts

```
var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried using Window.storage in the content script but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Jared, what if you call `localStorage.getItem("token")` directly in F12 tool?

Comment: On the webpage, I can call window.localStorage.getItem("token") in the chrome inspector it can access the token. maybe my content script isn't being injected right?

Comment: @Jared, yes, then I would suggest you check if the content script be injected. You can just open F12 tool -> Sources -> Content scripts and find if there exists your content scripts.

Comment: I checked the inspector and looks like my content script is not showing up on the content-script tab.

Comment: @Jared, that means your content script is not injected into web page. According to your question post, did your `matches` part in `manifest.json` exactly look like `"http://url/*`? You should know that only matches some url which contains `"url"`.  What about using `<all_urls>` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. no, that was just put in because I didn't want to put one of my companies internal URLs. I did get the script to finally start showing up as a content script in the F12 tool of the webpage. I added a webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated listener to the background script. However, I still can't get the token.